# Is it possible to use icon image as Launch image?

Tags: ios, xcode7

I am developing an iOS app and I am new to the environment. I just tried to add Launch Image to my app and I need the launch image to be the same as the icon image of the app.So can I use the icon as a launch Image or should I design other image?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend you use a LaunchScreen.storyboard rather than a LaunchScreen image. This way it will work for all device sizes and you can place whatever icon you want from your asset catalog in this storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Use your icon image in centre of launcher image and that will be enough to set it as launch image

Comment: I don't get it.can you elaborate? Thanks

Comment: as Hodson says, in LaunchScreen.storyboard simply place your app icon in centre of that view and apply Constraints, that should be enough. check this tutorial about launch screen storyboard.
https://useyourloaf.com/blog/using-a-launch-screen-storyboard/